# Bash Script to Detect Monitor

Tags: bash, debian, xrandr

I am trying to write a bash script to detect a monitor. I was able to find it with Xrandr but am not sure if this is the right method and unsure how to get the terminal to open in designated monitor.

I used this command to find the monitor:

```
xrandr --listmonitors
```

It gives me an Xwayland2 output for this monitor but i am unsure if this output is even usable. There is no guarantee it will always be Xwayland2. I then tried using:

```
if case "${SRANDRD_OUTPUT} ${SRANDRD_EVENT}" in
  "DVI-0 connected") xrandr --output DVI-0 --auto --right-of LVDS;;
  "VGA-0 connected") xrandr --output VGA-0 --auto --left-of LVDS;;
esac
then echo "hi"
```

I was able to get an output of hi which means it is detecting something, but i am not sure what it is detecting. I am also trying to get this to open on the Xwayland2 monitor by default rather than Xwayland0.

EDIT:

It will not let me comment now that this was moved to super user, so Im responding here to my own issue. The code that was given in the comment:

declare -A positions='([VGA-0]=left [DVI-0]=right)';{ read _;while read -r line;do display=${line#*  };[[ -v positions[$display] ]] && xrandr --output "${line#*  }" --auto --${positions[$display]}-of LVDS ;done;}< <(xrandr --listactivemonitors)
produces no output in the terminal.

The xrandr I grep \bconnected gives the following results in an array.

XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+2944+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 290mm

XWAYLAND1 connected 1920x1080+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm

XWAYLAND2 connected 1024x600+0+480 inverted (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 150mm x 90mm

Would it be easiest to have it detect the 1024x600+0+480 being that's unique?

Comment: What's the intention of the `if` ?

Comment: Just to test if true then give output i usually do hi. I usually end up using if statements in bash and don't have as much experience with case syntax. That's why it looks weird

Comment: Did `xrandr --listmonitors` command output some *`connected`* string?? On my config, this command output only `N+1` lines (1st line show *`Monitors: N`* and N lines showing each connected monitor, but no *`connected`* string are printed out). But **without** argument: `xrandr | grep \\bconnected`  did it!

Comment: Instead of `grep connected` use `--listactivemonitors` switch to `xrandr`!  Try this: `declare -A positions='([VGA-0]=left [DVI-0]=right)';{ read _;while read -r line;do display=${line#*  };[[ -v positions[$display] ]] && xrandr --output "${line#*  }" --auto --${positions[$display]}-of LVDS ;done;}< <(xrandr --listactivemonitors)` using associative array for expanding configuration.